# Call template-function with types in a tuple (not values)

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, variadic-templates

I would like to call a template function with no arguments for each type in a tuple. The code below shows exactly what the intention is.

My solution involves making a dummy instance of `DataGroup()`. I'd like to avoid this, as the types may not have a default constructor.

I've attempted to use `std::declval<DataGroup>()` instead, this results in
`'std::declval': Symbol involving type with internal linkage not defined` (in msvc).

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
void do_something_based_on_the_type()
{
    // ...
}

template<template <typename...> typename Tuple, typename... Ts>
void do_something_based_on_the_types_in_a_tuple(Tuple<Ts...>)
{
    (do_something_based_on_the_type<Ts>(), ...);
}

void some_code()
{
    struct Dataset1 {};
    struct Dataset2 {};
    struct Dataset3 {};
    using DataGroup = std::tuple<Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3>;

    do_something_based_on_the_types_in_a_tuple(DataGroup()); // -> ugly? requires a dummy instantiation of the tuple
}
```

---

My preferred solution, based on two of the answers together:

```
namespace internal
{

template<template <typename...> typename Tuple, typename TemplateFunc, typename... Ts>
void call_per_type_in_tuple(std::type_identity<Tuple<Ts...>>, TemplateFunc f)
{
    (f.template operator () < Ts > (), ...);
}

}

template<typename Tuple, typename TemplateFunc>
void call_foreach_tuple_type(TemplateFunc f)
{
    internal::call_per_type_in_tuple(std::type_identity<Tuple>(), std::forward<TemplateFunc>(f));
}

void example()
{
    struct Dataset1 {};
    struct Dataset2 {};
    struct Dataset3 {};
    using DataGroup = std::tuple<Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3>;

    call_foreach_tuple_type<DataGroup>([]<typename T>()
    {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Switch to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) which is always default-constructible

```
#include <type_traits>

template<template <typename...> typename Tuple, typename... Ts>
void do_something_based_on_the_types_in_a_tuple(std::type_identity<Tuple<Ts...>>)
{
    (do_something_based_on_the_type<Ts>(), ...);
}

using DataGroup = std::tuple<Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3>;
do_something_based_on_the_types_in_a_tuple(std::type_identity<DataGroup>());
```

Comment: `std::tuple<std::identity<T1>, std::identity<T2>>` should also be considered.

Answer (score 2):

Variant with class template specialization:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
void do_something_based_on_the_type()
{
    // ...
}

template<typename x_Tuple>
class t_ForEachItem;

template<typename... x_Items>
class t_ForEachItem<::std::tuple<x_Items...>>
{
    public: static void
    Do(){ (do_something_based_on_the_type<x_Items>(), ...); }
};

void some_code()
{
    struct Dataset1 {};
    struct Dataset2 {};
    struct Dataset3 {};
    using DataGroup = std::tuple<Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3>;

    t_ForEachItem<DataGroup>::Do();
}
```

It can also be used with a function call:

```
template<typename x_Tuple>
void do_something_based_on_the_types_in_a_tuple()
{
   t_ForEachItem<x_Tuple>::Do();
}
...
do_something_based_on_the_types_in_a_tuple<DataGroup>();
```

Generic variant:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename x_Tuple>
class t_ForEachItem;

template<typename... x_Items>
class t_ForEachItem<::std::tuple<x_Items...>>
{
    public: template<typename x_Fun> static void
    Do(x_Fun fun){ (fun.template operator ()<x_Items>(), ...); }
};

void some_code()
{
    struct Dataset1 {};
    struct Dataset2 {};
    struct Dataset3 {};
    using DataGroup = std::tuple<Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3>;

    t_ForEachItem<DataGroup>::Do([]<typename T>(){});
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+x_Tuple%3E%0Aclass+t_ForEachItem%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename...+x_Items%3E%0Aclass+t_ForEachItem%3C::std::tuple%3Cx_Items...%3E%3E%0A%7B%0A++++public:+template%3Ctypename+x_Fun%3E+static+void%0A++++Do(x_Fun+fun)%7B+(fun.template+operator+()%3Cx_Items%3E(),+...)%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+some_code()%0A%7B%0A++++struct+Dataset1+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++struct+Dataset2+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++struct+Dataset3+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++using+DataGroup+%3D+std::tuple%3CDataset1,+Dataset2,+Dataset3%3E%3B%0A%0A++++t_ForEachItem%3CDataGroup%3E::Do(%5B%5D%3Ctypename+T%3E()%7B%7D)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Any chance for a general version that allowes this: `t_ForEachItem<DataGroup>()::Do([]<typename T>(){ /*...*/ });`? passing a template lambda taking the type?

Comment: @Aedoro Sure, `Do` just needs a functor argument that will be invoked instead of `do_something_based_on_the_type`

Comment: I dont think it's that easy when the lambda requires a template argument? `template<typename F> static void Do(F func) { (func<x_Items>(), ...); }` is not valid.

Answer (score -3):

My solution is to use a helper function for type deduction. This helper function will take a pointer to a DataGroup instance, and use it to deduce the types in the tuple.

```
template<typename T>
void do_something_based_on_the_type()
{
    // ...
}

template<typename T>
void do_something_based_on_the_types_in_a_tuple_helper(T* dataGroup)
{
    std::apply([](auto&&... args){ (do_something_based_on_the_type<decltype(args)>(), ...); }, *dataGroup);
}

void some_code()
{
    struct Dataset1 {};
    struct Dataset2 {};
    struct Dataset3 {};
    using DataGroup = std::tuple<Dataset1, Dataset2, Dataset3>;

    DataGroup dataGroup;
    do_something_based_on_the_types_in_a_tuple_helper(&dataGroup);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).